Ways to bubble air in a solution without a bottle?
As title says, I'm doing a reaction that requires overnight air bubbling in the solution but I don't have a pressurised air bottle/cylinder (buying one is not an option as you have to also get s pressure reducer and that takes too long).
Up to know I've been using a (very) old vacuum pump with a tube to bubble the expelled air into the solution, but the flux is quite violent and it is advised that the bubbling should be gentle. Do you know of any good rudimental way to bubble air into a solution without an air bottle?

A fish tank bubbler?

Large balloon and a thin tube?

An aquarium fish tank bubbler, eventually with the aeration frit/stone seems an ideal choice to me. Available at near any pet shop.

If there is a large quantity of solution to be aerated, take two large containers, put one above the other, make a small hole at the bottom of the upper one (or use a siphon) and let the solution fall through the air instead of bubbling the air. There will be the same chemical process happening as with bubbling.
If the quantity of liquid is too small for this to last overnight, the best option is probably a fish tank bubbler, as already suggested in the comments.

@DrMoishePippik Edited. It's a simple question. Everybody knows liquids fall down from higher container to lower. Why not overnight, if the quantity is very large??

Thanks, that's something one can duplicate, and it might work -- if that is a sufficient quantity of air. In some cases, constant aeration is to drive out a species, or to oxidize the solution, and, in the proposed answer, most of the solution would not be exposed to the air, only that trickling down. The rest would be lying undisturbed in a the upper or lower container.
